# Running Powershell script from Java project wrapped as a service

Tags: java, powershell, service, yajsw

I am wrapping two java programs as services using yajsw (yet another java service wrapper) in order to have them run indefinitely on separate servers. I got one of them to work exactly as I expected (the service is installed on a server, behaves exactly as it does when run from cmd and restarts anytime it or the server goes down). However, when I do this with the second java project it does not work. It gets installed as a service and will run, but when it tries to run a powershell script (something the first project does not do) from within java, using ProcessBuilder(), it starts  and powershell.exe shows up in task manager, but never closes or produces any of the expected side effects. Both things that work seamlessly when I run the .jar from the command line. Is there something different about the environments that services/processes run in that would explain this?

Update:
Within the script I have the following line:
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;

The problem is that $outlook is null after this and the script then fails to parse any emails resulting in no output. What about wrapping the java program as a service would mess up the creation of an outlook application object?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm unsure if this is helpful as I just googled a bit and have no real experience on the subject, so I added it as a comment instead of an answer. 

Maybe try [this](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2010/01/26/running-powershell-scripts-as-a-service.aspx) way when building the process?

Comment: The Powershell script is not what needs to be running as a service. I have an infinite loop in java that runs a script each iteration; this is what I want the OS to run indefinitely.

Comment: Yea, I got that part. I just thought if there're parameters to be set when running a PS-script as a service, maybe those also need to be set when running it from within another service, if that makes any sense (I'm not sure that it does). Just another idea: if all you want to do is run a PS-script in an infinite loop maybe it'd be easier to implement that loop in PS and then run the script as a service?

Comment: kjosh I see what you're saying now, my bad. Just tried it out and it doesn't work though, fails with the same issue

Comment: If i run the wrapped program from a cmd without admin privileges it works. But I cannot install it as service from that window (because it doesnt have admin), and when I install it from one with admin rights it does not work (same problem as trying to run from cmd with admin rights

Comment: If it's not a problem to you your script outside of your Java frame maybe [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2bgtdh/best_practices_to_run_script_continuously_as_a/cj5d1hd) can help you?